# Efficient Algorithm for this simple game

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

We have N coins of type-1 and M coins of type-2. A game-board has N squares of type-1 and M squares of type-2. In this game we must place one coin into each square. After placing all coins we will get a score based on our coin placement strategy .

If type-1 square contains a type-1 coin then we will get A points, if type-2 square contains a type-2 coin then we will get B points and in all other cases, we will get C points.Our total game score will be sum of scores of all squares.

User Inputs Available are ( N,M,A,B,C )

How can we maximize our score ?

e.g if N=3 M=4 A=500 B=800 C=600

With optimal strategy we will place 3 coins of type-1 into 3 squares of type-1 getting score =500+500+500 = 1500 and we will place 4 coins of type-2 into 4 squares of type-2 getting score =800+800+800+800 = 3200 so total score will be 1500+3200 = 4700

Comment: @CyberDrone One usually maximizes numbers like cost, quantity, time(in seconds). But you are trying to maximize sum like 4A+6B+4C which makes no sense. Give values to A, B, C or atleast tell like A>B>C, N>M. Do you understand what i mean ?

Comment: I am relatively new to coding and I just want to figure out a proper algorithm before I implement it.I am not looking for an actual code , I just need help with developing the algorithm.It would be really great if someone could help me out with the logic

Comment: @CyberDrone this question is still vague, because we don't even have a hint of of what is the pattern of game board, how are n(type-1) and m(type-2) squares placed. If we could distinguish between type-1 square and type-2 square(also between types of coins), we could then work on optimality based on purely(see LPP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) linear equations in two variables with given objective function as our total score.

Comment: We can consider type 1 squares and coins to be red in color and type 2 squares and coins to be blue in color.The spatial arrangement of the square has no significance for this questions so we can assume any arrangement of the squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. One obviously valid solution is to place all type-1 coins at type-1 squares. This will give you a certain score. We could now swap any type-1 coin with a type-2 coin. Doing so, we will lose a score of `A + B` but gain `2 C`. So, swapping makes only sense if `2 C > A + B`. And we can swap `min(N, M)` times. So the maximum score is:

```
nSwaps =  
    if 2 * C > A + B then
        min(N, M)
    else
        0
    end if

maxScore = N * A + M * B + nSwaps * (2 * C - A - B)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Its a really good solution.I tried to solve it using dynamic programming but was not able to find an overlapping sub-structure